# Rails Query Includes acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to Query for top casts (kind of like posts) based on how many votes they got.

Acts_as_votable gem, and currently my casts are votable. I can vote on them and retrieve their upvotes - downvotes, but i need to query for the top casts. Please Help!

Below did not work

'<% cast_query = Cast.includes(:votes).order('vote_flag').all %>'

Saying 'vote_flag' unrecognized, but I looked into my Postgresql and that's the name of the column that has 1 or 0 for upvote or downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vote_flag column is on votes, not casts.  So that's not going to work unless you do a join instead of an includes.

You probably want to follow the instructions here - https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching - on setting up a cached vote count on the votable object (in your case Cast) and sort by that cached value.  This will be reasonably performant.

Alternately, you can do a join with the votes table, group by casts.*, and order by the sum of the vote_flag.  But that's a lot more complicated.